# How to make a div update the content with a sliding effect (animation similar to flash)?

Tags: javascript, css, flash, animation, sliding

Could you please tell me how this photo animation effect is achieved - see the pictures that slide seamlessly to the left every say 3 seconds (the pictures just below the BIGSTOCKPHOTO logo).. Site- www.bigstockphoto.com

I have noted this effect being used in many other sites.. And none of them seem to employ flash for making this. Please let me know whether this is just JS or whether its purely a CSS based effect, and probably a place where i can read on how to make this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go..

example:
http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/01.html

info:
http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider

Comment: awesome.. exactly what I was looking for. 
I was wondering, though, whether it is possible to make using just pure javascript and/ css, without any other plugins.

Comment: yes it is.... but I recomend the usage of a javascript library such as jquery, because it will simplify your implementation...